# Android RxJava: I am not unsubscribing after onComplete

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a class called `PendingRequests`. This class is basically a counter for Volley Requests. I have two Volley methods - One called `CheckOpen` and one called `CheckCompleted`. Each methods selects either Open or Completed records on my SQLite tablet database and checks them against the server.

In `CheckOpen` and `CheckClose`, I use three calls to `PendingRequests`. At the start I call `Initialize()`, then as I add a volley request to the queue I call `Add()` and then as I begin to receive responses I call `Subtract()`. For both `CheckOpen` or `CheckClose` I will very quickly `Add()` up to 50 and then slowly countdown (`Subtract()`) back to zero.

Once I countdown to zero, I call `onComplete`.

Here is the code for `PendingRequests`

```java
import rx.Observable;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;
import rx.subjects.Subject;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 6/17/15.
 */
public class PendingRequests {
    private static Integer pendingReq;
    private static Subject<Integer, Integer> pendingObser = PublishSubject.create();

    public static void Initialize(Integer myInt) {
        pendingReq = myInt;
        pendingObser.onNext(pendingReq);
    }

    public static void Add() {
        pendingReq ++;
        pendingObser.onNext(pendingReq);
    }

    public static void Subtract() {
        if (pendingReq == 0) {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            pendingReq --;
            if (pendingReq == 0) {
                pendingObser.onCompleted();
            }
            else {
                pendingObser.onNext(pendingReq);
            }

        }
    }

    public static Integer Current() {
        // return the current value of pendingReq for testing purposes
        return pendingReq;
    }

    public static Observable<Integer> valueChanged() {
        return pendingObser;
    }
}
```

So from above `PendingObser` is a Subject and `valueChanged` is the Observer. (Hopefully I understand that correctly).

In my `MainActivity` I have two buttons. Beside each button is a `textview` that shows the value coming from `pendingObser`.

Here is the code for my two buttons

```java
public void checkComplete(View view) {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResendActivity.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
    PendingRequests.valueChanged().subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            tvPendingTotalClosed.setText("Done");
            System.gc();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            tvPendingTotalClosed.setText(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            tvPendingTotalClosed.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
        }
    });
    String myResult = seWebServiceUtils.checkCompletedRecord();
    Toast.makeText(ApplicationController.getContext(), myResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void checkOpen(View view){
    // called directly from button btnCheckOpen
    PendingRequests.valueChanged().subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
           tvPendingTotalOpen.setText("Done");
            System.gc();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            tvPendingTotalOpen.setText(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            tvPendingTotalOpen.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
        }
    });
    String myResult = seWebServiceUtils.checkOpenRecord();
    Toast.makeText(ApplicationController.getContext(), myResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I have two problems:

1. When I call `checkComplete` it performs as expected and will end with the word Done in `tvPendingTotalClosed`. However, when I hit `checkOpen` BOTH `tvPendingTotalClosed` and `tvPendingTotalOpen` count down. So `checkComplete` is not unsubscribing
2. After hitting the buttons the first time, if I try to hit the button `CheckOpenRecords` a second time nothing happens. It is like I can't re-subscribe to `PendingRequests` a second time.

Thanks, John

Comment: Hi. Have you tried to subscribe directly to the `PublishSubject`? Are you having the save results?
Try to initialize it as `public static PublishSubject<Integer> pendingObser = PublishSubject.create();`